# Sorting artifacts using aql and cleanup old artifacts

Tags: api, sorting, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to sort the list of artifacts from jfrog artifactory but getting (The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request), in the jfrog documentation (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Comparison+Matrix) says it won't work for open source services. After we get list of artifacts need to delete old artifacts from subfolder in the artifactory repo. Tried with CLI and AQL but nothing worked.

Our repo url looks like this
`http://domainname/artifactory/repo/folder/subfolder/test1.zip`

Like test 1.zip we have many artifacts(let's say 50)in that subfolder. Looking for help on this, anyone pls me on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While sorting is not supported in OSS versions, if you would like to delete artifacts older than a certain time period, you can use [Relative Time Operators](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-RelativeTimeOperators), parse the output, and use a script to delete those artifacts.
You can also specify a [specific date](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-DateandTimeFormat). There are several [Comparison Operators](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-ComparisonOperators) that you can use.
You can use the below AQL for reference:

```
curl -uadmin:password -XPOST "http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/search/aql" -d 'items.find({"repo": "repo"}, {"path": "folder/subfolder"}, {"created" : {"$before" : "2minutes"}})'  -H "Content-Type: text/plain"
```